# Error while trying to return one column from SQL Server function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I have a function in SQL Server with a select statement and I want to return one row calculated inside the select statement - `ORDER_VALUE_ADJUSTED`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION order_value 
    (@date DATE, 
     @client VARCHAR(50), 
     @order_number VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS DECIMAL(13,2) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        EKKO.EBELN, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN EKPO.NETWR = CDPOS.VALUE_NEW AND CDHDR.UDATE >= @date THEN CDPOS.VALUE_OLD ELSE EKPO.NETWR END) AS ORDER_VALUE_ADJUSTED
    FROM 
        EKKO
    INNER JOIN 
        EKPO_C AS EKPO ON EKKO.EBELN = EKPO.EBELN 
                       AND EKKO.MANDT = EKPO.MANDT
    LEFT JOIN 
        CDPOS_C AS CDPOS ON (EKPO.MANDT + EKPO.EBELN + EKPO.EBELP) = CDPOS.TABKEY
    LEFT JOIN 
        CDHDR ON CDHDR.CHANGENR = CDPOS.CHANGENR
    WHERE 
        EKKO.MANDT = @client 
        AND EKKO.EBELN = @order_number
    GROUP BY 
        EKKO.EBELN

    RETURN ORDER_VALUE_ADJUSTED
END;
```

I am getting these errors:

> Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure order_value, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure order_value, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Invalid column name 'ORDER_VALUE_ADJUSTED'.

How can I solve this issue ? Do I need to rewrite it into a stored procedure ?

Comment: I dont know sqlserver, but I suspect several problems. Your select is a table, and your function return a scalar,that cant be right

Comment: You have a `SELECT` with a `GROUP BY` that most likely will return multiple rows - which one of those rows do you want to use as your return value?? Not clear....

Comment: You need to either `RETURN` your select, or assign the value from your select into a variable and return that. That said Inline Table Valued Functions perform much better generally than a scalar function. There are loads of examples you can copy out there, the official documentation would be a great place to start.

Comment: Does the query return only one row?

Comment: @Agar123, since the group is fixed by one of the argument that is my guess

Comment: Your function skeleton syntax has nothing to do with SQL Server UDF, that can return a value (scalar function) from a variable beginning by @, or can return a table (table inline aka ITVF , or multi-statement aka MSTVF) that needs a table definition and must return a SELECT... Check the online ref manual to learn Transact SQL.

Comment: @marc_s I want to return one column only -  ORDER_VALUE_ADJUSTED. The result of the case when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issues are that you are trying to `SELECT` straight out of the function, and you are not storing the data into variables to `RETURN`.

But it sounds like you actually need an inline Table Valued Function, rather than a Scalar Function, these are in any case much faster

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.order_value 
    (@date DATE, 
     @client VARCHAR(50), 
     @order_number VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    SELECT 
        EKKO.EBELN, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN EKPO.NETWR = CDPOS.VALUE_NEW AND CDHDR.UDATE >= @date THEN CDPOS.VALUE_OLD ELSE EKPO.NETWR END) AS ORDER_VALUE_ADJUSTED
    FROM 
        EKKO
    INNER JOIN 
        EKPO_C AS EKPO ON EKKO.EBELN = EKPO.EBELN 
                       AND EKKO.MANDT = EKPO.MANDT
    LEFT JOIN 
        CDPOS_C AS CDPOS ON (EKPO.MANDT + EKPO.EBELN + EKPO.EBELP) = CDPOS.TABKEY
    LEFT JOIN 
        CDHDR ON CDHDR.CHANGENR = CDPOS.CHANGENR
    WHERE 
        EKKO.MANDT = @client 
        AND EKKO.EBELN = @order_number
    GROUP BY 
        EKKO.EBELN
;
```

An inline table function must be a single `RETURN SELECT` statement.

You use it like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.order_value(GETDATE(), 'SomeClient', 'SomeOrder') ov;
```

Or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Orders o
CROSS APPLY dbo.order_value(o.Date, o.Client, o.Number) ov;
```

Answer (score 0):

A guess, can't verify the syntax at the moment:

```
CREATE FUNCTION order_value 
(@date DATE, 
 @client VARCHAR(50), 
 @order_number VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS DECIMAL(13,2) 
RETURN
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN EKPO.NETWR = CDPOS.VALUE_NEW AND CDHDR.UDATE >= @date 
                THEN CDPOS.VALUE_OLD 
                ELSE EKPO.NETWR 
           END) AS ORDER_VALUE_ADJUSTED
FROM EKKO
INNER JOIN EKPO_C AS EKPO 
    ON EKKO.EBELN = EKPO.EBELN 
   AND EKKO.MANDT = EKPO.MANDT
LEFT JOIN CDPOS_C AS CDPOS 
    ON (EKPO.MANDT + EKPO.EBELN + EKPO.EBELP) = CDPOS.TABKEY
LEFT JOIN CDHDR 
    ON CDHDR.CHANGENR = CDPOS.CHANGENR
WHERE EKKO.MANDT = @client 
  AND EKKO.EBELN = @order_number;
```